# Setting a value in a textbox from another form

Tags: vb.net

I'm using vb.net 2013.I have 3 forms : Form1, Form2, Form3

On form1 I have a button . When this button is pressed , the form2 is open.The code inside the click event is :

```
Dim dlg1 As New Form2

dlg1.Show(Me)
```

Inside From2 I have a TextBox (Txt1) and a button .When this button is clicked the Form3 is open.The code inside the click event is :

```
Dim dlg2 As New Form3

dlg2.Show(Me)
```

Inside form3 I have a button that I use to set a value in the textbox (txt1) on Form2. I use this code :

```
Form2.txt1.Text="123"
```

The problem is that after I press the button on form3 , the textbox on form2 is empty , no value is set.

What can I do ? ( I don't want to change the way the forms are open)

Thank you !

Comment: your Form2 *instance* is called dlg2, so reference it that way (provided that dialog is still open).  Form2 simply references the form class

Comment: The wonders of automatic instances.....

Answer (score 1):

`Form2.txt1` references [default instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233839.aspx) of the form.

You are using a new instance here:

```
Dim dlg1 As New Form2
```

You either need to replace this code:

```
Dim dlg1 As New Form2
dlg1.Show(Me)
```

With

```
Form2.Show(Me) 'not recommended
```

Or cast your form's `Owner` to your previous form's type, and set the property (recommended):

```
DirectCast(Me.Owner, Form2).txt1.Text = "123"
```

Comment: I try to use this code : CType(Me.Owner, Form2).Txt1.Text = "123" but there's the same problem.No text on textbox.

Comment: @alex: Please paste all code you have (or create an empty project, try to reproduce it there, and provide that as a reference). Unless there is some detail we are missing, the approach should work. Other code could be interfering, however.

Comment: There's no other code. Only the code that open the forms and the code that set the value to textbox.

Comment: @alex: Can you share the project as a ZIP file then? I could have a look then.

Comment: I don't know why but only this works :

Dim fr as Form2=DirectCast(Me.Owner,Form2)

fr.txt1.text="123"

Comment: @alex: isn't it exactly what I suggested? :)

Answer (score 0):

Just open The forms with Form2.Show() , Form3.Show()
Then If you put this in your Form3 button click event " Form2.txt1.Text="123" " It will work.

Comment: dlg1 is most likely not accessible within the scope of dlg2.